# Error creating bean with name 'app.dev.demo.DemoApplicationTests': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userrepository'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm new in jee and spring boot and I'm struggling with this issue a few days ago, any advice or help will be appreciated. I tried the proposed solutions in similar issue, however it's not working for me.

**POM.XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>app.dev</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging> 

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>  
        </dependency> 

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/db_dev
spring.datasource.username=user1
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB53Dialect
pring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.=error
```

**ApplicationTest**

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import app.dev.demo.model.User;
import repository.userRepository;

import static org.junit.Assert.*; 
import org.junit.Before;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DemoApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private userRepository userrepository;
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        User user1= new User("Alice", "Alice@gmail.com", "alice", "admin");
        User user2= new User("Bob", "Bob@gmail.com", "bob", "user");
        //save user, verify has ID value after save
        assertNull(user1.getId());
        assertNull(user2.getId());//null before save
        this.userrepository.save(user1);
        this.userrepository.save(user2);
        assertNotNull(user1.getId());
        assertNotNull(user2.getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {

         /*Test data retrieval*/
        User userA = userrepository.findByName("Bob");
        assertNotNull(userA);
        /*Get all products, list should only have two*/
        Iterable<User> users = userrepository.findAll();
        int count = 0;
        for(User p : users){
            count++;
        }
        assertEquals(count, 2);
    }
}
```

**UserRepository**

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import app.dev.demo.model.User;

@Repository
public interface userRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{

    //List<User> findByName(String name);
    User findByName(String name);

}
```

As error I got this while trying to run the test:

```
2019-03-18 12:21:03 ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@35cabb2a] to prepare test instance [app.dev.demo.DemoApplicationTests@2589d787]
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'app.dev.demo.DemoApplicationTests': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userrepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'repository.userRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1395)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:391)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'repository.userRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1654)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.152 s <<< FAILURE! - in app.dev.demo.DemoApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads(app.dev.demo.DemoApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.015 s  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'app.dev.demo.DemoApplicationTests': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userrepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'repository.userRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'repository.userRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

**Update:**

**Spring Boot Application**

```
import app.dev.demo.model.User;
import repository.userRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({ "archi.dev.demo" })
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
```

What I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: show the main class, i can see your packages are not in a structure

Comment: Spring cannot find bean userRepository - `repository.userRepository`. Is 'repository' package scanned by SpringBoot? Check @ComponentScan annotation or show please your config file

Comment: I have added the main class to my my post, and yes I have used the @ComponentScan annotation

Answer (score 0):

try adding something like this to your junit test

```
@TestConfiguration
static class testContextConfiguration {

   @Bean
   public userRepository userRepository() {
       return new userRepository();
   }
}
```

Or
you can try annotating your test class with @DataJpaTest if you're only going to test repository related actions

PS.: Maybe you already know that, but by convention, your classes should begin with a capital letter;
The variable names may not begin with the capital, but the subsequent words should;
So: UserRepository userRepository;

Comment: adding `@DataJpaTest` to my test class makes it in conflict with `@SpringBootTest` annotation, using it alone, the issue maintains